# iPhone/OS X: Convert UTC format date&time value Calendar required format

Tags: iphone, macos

I am struggling a bit to convert the UTC time to the date format what i want.

```
2012-03-10T09:30:00Z
```

needs to be converted to the below format

```
3:00:00pm April 19, 2012
```

Could you someone please help me to resolve this?

I tried like below,

```
    NSString *formatted;
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] ;
    [formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss EEEE, MMM d"];
// Here datetime= 2012-03-10T09:30:00Z
    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970: [datetime intValue]]; 
    NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"dateString: %@", dateString);
```

But, its printing wrong date like "06:03:32 Thursday, Jan 1". Please correct me.

**UPDATED:**  I am having another problem, its not giving me the correct time, but its giving the correct date though. My Code is below.

```
NSString *formatted;
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] ;
[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss EEEE, MMM d"];


NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:datetime];
NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"dateString: %@", dateString);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert an ISO date string to `NSDate`:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:date_str];
```

You can then convert it to your local time zone:

```
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
[df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss EEEE, MMM d"];
```

In your code, your `[datetime intValue]` is probably incorrect.

Comment: Then to get the output you've shown, use the following format [formatter setDateFormat:@"K:mm:ssa MMM, d yyyy"];

Comment: Hi Shiming, Thanks. I think, i want the format to be in reverse way.

Comment: Hi Whitetiger, Your format doesn't created. It is showing null.

Comment: Ok. I resolved the format issue like this, [formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss EEEE, MMM d"];  so its give me like 23:30:00 Friday, May 4.

Comment: Oh ok, i think Mr.Shiming you have already posted that too. Sorry i didn't see that earlier. Thank you very much.

Comment: I am having another problem, its not giving me the correct time, but its giving the correct date though. My Code is updated in my question above.

Comment: The time should be correct. If not, your original ISO date representation is wrong. "2012-03-10T09:30:00Z" represents 2012-03-10 09:30 in Greenwich Time. What results are you getting and what's your local time zone?

Comment: Yes, this is what i'm getting from server which is located in U.S. 2012-03-10T09:30:00Z. I'm in India now and debugging this project, its giving me 15:00:00 Saturday, Mar 10.

Comment: Try this link: http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converted.html?day=10&month=3&year=2012&hour=9&min=30&sec=0&p1=0&p2=176 . "2012-03-10T09:30:00Z" is "15:00:00 Saturday, Mar 10." in New Delhi. Regardless of the server location, the date representation is in ISO, which as I said, represents Greenwich Mean Time, not any U.S. time zone.

Comment: Hi Shiming, Thanks for the reply. Are you saying what i'm getting is the right value? I don't need to do any more conversion right? Please advise.